# Ecclesiastes "Worthless" or unclaimable?

Tags: hebrew

The writer of Ecclesiastes repeatedly describes life, effort, and death as "worthless" or "vain". But I have heard many saying that the word "hebel" does not mean worthless, but rather hard to figure out, which seems to make sense. Which one is correct?

Comment: See the translations commended in the above link. Personally I find 'vapor' to be a really good match - that really changed the way in which I understood the whole book. 'Vapor' is light and momentary, and can be blown away or disappear easily. It captures that sense of meaninglessness and ephemerality fairly well.